# Summarize several columns with looping through columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pivot-table, reshape

I have a very strange survey data structure like the below sample. During the survey number of smartphone per household were collected and then collect information about how many individuals use each device for a particular activity.

Exmple : F3_{smartphone number}_{HH_member_id} so F3_1_4  will be F3 & {first Household smartphone}=1 & {Number of Household_member_using/sharing this device = 4}

Or if 3 members in the household shearing a device , F3_1_1, F3_1_2, F3_1_3 will be 1.

I am trying to pull out individual devices and calculate number of phones used for that activity and by how many. Here is my try

```
df_ph = pd.DataFrame()

   
for h in range(1,5):

  df_shared_ph = pd.DataFrame(None)

  for i in range(1,15):
    
    df_temp_ph = df[["respid", "f3_" + str(h) + "_" + str(i)]].copy()
    df_temp_ph.rename(columns = {"f3_" + str(h) + "_" + str(i): "Smartph"}, inplace = True)
    df_shared_ph = pd.concat([df_shared_ph, df_temp_ph], axis=0).dropna(subset=["Smartph"])

  df_shared_ph = df_shared_ph.groupby(['respid']).agg({'Smartph': 'sum'}).reset_index()
  df_ph = pd.concat([df_ph, df_shared_ph], axis=0)

  print("used for X and by how many:\n" + str(df_ph['Smartph'].value_counts()))
```

My snippet is working without error but it will duplicate many rows/id in my original data for some reason and I couldn't figure out why. Am I missing something here? is there an alternative way to do this?

```
df_ph.duplicated(['respid']).sum() == 0
False
```

Sample data:

```
# output to a dict
# the dict can be converted to a dataframe with 
# df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')  # d is the name of the dict


 {0: {'f3_1_1': 1.0, 'f3_1_10': nan,  'f3_1_11': nan,  'f3_1_12': nan,  'f3_1_13': nan,'f3_1_14': nan,   'f3_1_15': nan,  'f3_1_2': 0.0,
    'f3_1_3': 0.0,'f3_1_4': 0.0,'f3_1_5': nan,'f3_1_6': nan,  'f3_1_7': nan,  'f3_1_8': nan,  'f3_1_9': nan,  'f3_2_1': 0.0,  'f3_2_10': nan,
    'f3_2_11': nan,  'f3_2_12': nan,  'f3_2_13': nan,   'f3_2_14': nan,   'f3_2_15': nan,   'f3_2_2': 1.0,  'f3_2_3': 0.0,  'f3_2_4': 0.0,
    'f3_2_5': nan,  'f3_2_6': nan,  'f3_2_7': nan,  'f3_2_8': nan,  'f3_2_9': nan,  'f3_3_1': 0.0,  'f3_3_10': nan,   'f3_3_11': nan,
    'f3_3_12': nan,    'f3_3_13': nan,    'f3_3_14': nan,    'f3_3_15': nan,    'f3_3_2': 0.0,    'f3_3_3': 1.0,    'f3_3_4': 0.0,
    'f3_3_5': nan,    'f3_3_6': nan,    'f3_3_7': nan,    'f3_3_8': nan,    'f3_3_9': nan,    'f3_4_1': 0.0,    'f3_4_10': nan,
    'f3_4_11': nan,    'f3_4_12': nan,    'f3_4_13': nan,    'f3_4_14': nan,    'f3_4_15': nan,    'f3_4_2': 0.0,    'f3_4_3': 0.0,
    'f3_4_4': 1.0,    'f3_4_5': nan,    'f3_4_6': nan,    'f3_4_7': nan,    'f3_4_8': nan,    'f3_4_9': nan,    'f3_5_1': nan,
    'f3_5_10': nan,    'f3_5_11': nan,    'f3_5_12': nan,    'f3_5_13': nan,    'f3_5_14': nan,    'f3_5_15': nan,    'f3_5_2': nan,
    'f3_5_3': nan,    'f3_5_4': nan,    'f3_5_5': nan,    'f3_5_6': nan,    'f3_5_7': nan,    'f3_5_8': nan,    'f3_5_9': nan,
    'respid': 13766.0},
    1: {'f3_1_1': nan,   'f3_1_10': nan,  'f3_1_11': nan, 'f3_1_12': nan, 'f3_1_13': nan, 'f3_1_14': nan,  'f3_1_15': nan,  'f3_1_2': nan,
      'f3_1_3': nan,    'f3_1_4': nan,    'f3_1_5': nan,  'f3_1_6': nan,  'f3_1_7': nan,  'f3_1_8': nan,  'f3_1_9': nan,    'f3_2_1': nan,
      'f3_2_10': nan,      'f3_2_11': nan,      'f3_2_12': nan,      'f3_2_13': nan,      'f3_2_14': nan,      'f3_2_15': nan,      'f3_2_2': nan,
      'f3_2_3': nan,      'f3_2_4': nan,      'f3_2_5': nan,      'f3_2_6': nan,      'f3_2_7': nan,      'f3_2_8': nan,
      'f3_2_9': nan,      'f3_3_1': nan,      'f3_3_10': nan,      'f3_3_11': nan,      'f3_3_12': nan,      'f3_3_13': nan,
      'f3_3_14': nan,      'f3_3_15': nan,      'f3_3_2': nan,      'f3_3_3': nan,      'f3_3_4': nan,      'f3_3_5': nan,
      'f3_3_6': nan,      'f3_3_7': nan,      'f3_3_8': nan,      'f3_3_9': nan,      'f3_4_1': nan,      'f3_4_10': nan,      'f3_4_11': nan,
      'f3_4_12': nan,      'f3_4_13': nan,      'f3_4_14': nan,      'f3_4_15': nan,      'f3_4_2': nan,      'f3_4_3': nan,
      'f3_4_4': nan,      'f3_4_5': nan,      'f3_4_6': nan,      'f3_4_7': nan,      'f3_4_8': nan,      'f3_4_9': nan,      'f3_5_1': nan,
      'f3_5_10': nan,      'f3_5_11': nan,      'f3_5_12': nan,      'f3_5_13': nan,      'f3_5_14': nan,      'f3_5_15': nan,      'f3_5_2': nan,
      'f3_5_3': nan,      'f3_5_4': nan,      'f3_5_5': nan,      'f3_5_6': nan,      'f3_5_7': nan,      'f3_5_8': nan,      'f3_5_9': nan,
      'respid': 16346.0},
    2: {'f3_1_1': 1.0,      'f3_1_10': nan,      'f3_1_11': nan,      'f3_1_12': nan,      'f3_1_13': nan,      'f3_1_14': nan,      'f3_1_15': nan,
      'f3_1_2': 0.0,      'f3_1_3': nan,      'f3_1_4': nan,      'f3_1_5': nan,      'f3_1_6': nan,      'f3_1_7': nan,      'f3_1_8': nan,
      'f3_1_9': nan,      'f3_2_1': 0.0,      'f3_2_10': nan,      'f3_2_11': nan,      'f3_2_12': nan,      'f3_2_13': nan,
      'f3_2_14': nan,      'f3_2_15': nan,      'f3_2_2': 1.0,      'f3_2_3': nan,      'f3_2_4': nan,      'f3_2_5': nan,      'f3_2_6': nan,
      'f3_2_7': nan,      'f3_2_8': nan,      'f3_2_9': nan,      'f3_3_1': nan,      'f3_3_10': nan,      'f3_3_11': nan,      'f3_3_12': nan,
      'f3_3_13': nan,      'f3_3_14': nan,      'f3_3_15': nan,      'f3_3_2': nan,      'f3_3_3': nan,      'f3_3_4': nan,      'f3_3_5': nan,
      'f3_3_6': nan,      'f3_3_7': nan,      'f3_3_8': nan,      'f3_3_9': nan,      'f3_4_1': nan,      'f3_4_10': nan,      'f3_4_11': nan,
      'f3_4_12': nan,      'f3_4_13': nan,      'f3_4_14': nan,      'f3_4_15': nan,      'f3_4_2': nan,      'f3_4_3': nan,      'f3_4_4': nan,
      'f3_4_5': nan,      'f3_4_6': nan,      'f3_4_7': nan,      'f3_4_8': nan,      'f3_4_9': nan,      'f3_5_1': nan,      'f3_5_10': nan,
      'f3_5_11': nan,      'f3_5_12': nan,      'f3_5_13': nan,      'f3_5_14': nan,      'f3_5_15': nan,      'f3_5_2': nan,      'f3_5_3': nan,
      'f3_5_4': nan,      'f3_5_5': nan,      'f3_5_6': nan,      'f3_5_7': nan,      'f3_5_8': nan,      'f3_5_9': nan,      'respid': 11293.0},
    3: {'f3_1_1': nan,
      'f3_1_10': nan,      'f3_1_11': nan,      'f3_1_12': nan,      'f3_1_13': nan,      'f3_1_14': nan,      'f3_1_15': nan,      'f3_1_2': nan,
      'f3_1_3': nan,      'f3_1_4': nan,      'f3_1_5': nan,      'f3_1_6': nan,      'f3_1_7': nan,      'f3_1_8': nan,      'f3_1_9': nan,      'f3_2_1': nan,
      'f3_2_10': nan,      'f3_2_11': nan,      'f3_2_12': nan,      'f3_2_13': nan,      'f3_2_14': nan,      'f3_2_15': nan,      'f3_2_2': nan,
      'f3_2_3': nan,      'f3_2_4': nan,      'f3_2_5': nan,      'f3_2_6': nan,      'f3_2_7': nan,      'f3_2_8': nan,  'f3_2_9': nan,  'f3_3_1': nan,
      'f3_3_10': nan,      'f3_3_11': nan,      'f3_3_12': nan,      'f3_3_13': nan,      'f3_3_14': nan,      'f3_3_15': nan,      'f3_3_2': nan,
      'f3_3_3': nan,      'f3_3_4': nan,      'f3_3_5': nan,      'f3_3_6': nan,      'f3_3_7': nan,      'f3_3_8': nan,      'f3_3_9': nan,
      'f3_4_1': nan,      'f3_4_10': nan,      'f3_4_11': nan,      'f3_4_12': nan,      'f3_4_13': nan,      'f3_4_14': nan,      'f3_4_15': nan,
      'f3_4_2': nan,      'f3_4_3': nan,      'f3_4_4': nan,      'f3_4_5': nan,      'f3_4_6': nan,      'f3_4_7': nan,      'f3_4_8': nan,
      'f3_4_9': nan,      'f3_5_1': nan,      'f3_5_10': nan,      'f3_5_11': nan,      'f3_5_12': nan,      'f3_5_13': nan,      'f3_5_14': nan,
      'f3_5_15': nan,      'f3_5_2': nan,      'f3_5_3': nan,      'f3_5_4': nan,      'f3_5_5': nan,      'f3_5_6': nan,      'f3_5_7': nan,
      'f3_5_8': nan,      'f3_5_9': nan,      'respid': 15965.0},
    4: {'f3_1_1': 1.0,      'f3_1_10': nan,      'f3_1_11': nan,      'f3_1_12': nan,      'f3_1_13': nan,      'f3_1_14': nan,
      'f3_1_15': nan,      'f3_1_2': 0.0,      'f3_1_3': 0.0,      'f3_1_4': nan,      'f3_1_5': nan,      'f3_1_6': nan,      'f3_1_7': nan,
      'f3_1_8': nan,      'f3_1_9': nan,      'f3_2_1': 0.0,      'f3_2_10': nan,      'f3_2_11': nan,      'f3_2_12': nan,      'f3_2_13': nan,
      'f3_2_14': nan,      'f3_2_15': nan,      'f3_2_2': 1.0,      'f3_2_3': 0.0,      'f3_2_4': nan,      'f3_2_5': nan,      'f3_2_6': nan,
      'f3_2_7': nan,      'f3_2_8': nan,      'f3_2_9': nan,      'f3_3_1': 0.0,      'f3_3_10': nan,      'f3_3_11': nan,      'f3_3_12': nan,
      'f3_3_13': nan,      'f3_3_14': nan,      'f3_3_15': nan,      'f3_3_2': 0.0,      'f3_3_3': 1.0,      'f3_3_4': nan,      'f3_3_5': nan,
      'f3_3_6': nan,      'f3_3_7': nan,      'f3_3_8': nan,      'f3_3_9': nan,      'f3_4_1': nan,      'f3_4_10': nan,      'f3_4_11': nan,
      'f3_4_12': nan,      'f3_4_13': nan,      'f3_4_14': nan,      'f3_4_15': nan,      'f3_4_2': nan,      'f3_4_3': nan,      'f3_4_4': nan,
      'f3_4_5': nan,      'f3_4_6': nan,      'f3_4_7': nan,      'f3_4_8': nan,      'f3_4_9': nan,      'f3_5_1': nan,      'f3_5_10': nan,
      'f3_5_11': nan,      'f3_5_12': nan,      'f3_5_13': nan,      'f3_5_14': nan,      'f3_5_15': nan,      'f3_5_2': nan,      'f3_5_3': nan,
      'f3_5_4': nan,      'f3_5_5': nan,      'f3_5_6': nan,      'f3_5_7': nan,      'f3_5_8': nan,      'f3_5_9': nan,      'respid': 7110.0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you have encoded multi-index columns.  You can decode as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').set_index("respid")  # d is the name of the dict
# remove redundant "f3_" from column name
df = df.rename(columns={c:c[3:] for c in df.columns if c.startswith("f3_")})

# F3_{smartphone number}_{HH_member_id}
# make columns a multiindex
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split("_")) for c in df.columns], names=["smartphone_no","household_id"])
# now its simple to work with DF
df.stack()
```

#### output

```
smartphone_no           1    2    3    4   5
respid  household_id                        
13766.0 1             1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
        2             0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
        3             0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0 NaN
        4             0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 NaN
11293.0 1             1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN NaN
        2             0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
7110.0  1             1.0  0.0  0.0  NaN NaN
        2             0.0  1.0  0.0  NaN NaN
        3             0.0  0.0  1.0  NaN NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. No matter how hard I try, there is always an easier way :)